# Error previewing page with DXA 2.0 TBBs

Tags: dxa, dxa-2.0

I am in the process of upgrading a DXA 1.8 CM to DXA 2.0. I have ensured that my Page Template is using the new DXA 2.0 **Generate DXA R2 Page Model** TBB. I am getting errors when publishing/previewing as follows:

> (80040200) An error occurred while rendering Page 'Home'
>   (tcm:56-1409-64) No items found for WebDAV URL(s):
>   /webdav/MyPub/Home/_System/include/header.tpg.

I dont have an include page with title **header** in my implementation (it contains a module name prefix - mymodule:Header to enable the correct views to be used in the web application), so I am not sure where this is coming from? ... and why is it bothering with Includes when publishing the page anyway - the whole point of these is that they are separate from page publishing.

Edit - I think I have found the culprit: 
https://github.com/sdl/dxa-content-management/blob/25873210b246ab397dfc8efd0b63f30e1c5243f1/Sdl.Web.Tridion.Templates.R2/Data/DefaultModelBuilder.cs#L301
It seems that DXA 2.0 assumes that your include page title matches the URL. It also assumes all includes are in /system/include. This could cause problems for implementations where includes are in different places (for example to enable that different types of users can/cannot edit them).

Comment: Opened an issue: https://github.com/sdl/dxa-content-management/issues/10

Answer (score 2):

The idea in DXA 2.0 was to move towards managed links for include Pages. For backwards compatibility purposes you can still use published URLs, but you can also use a TCM URI or WebDAV URL of the Page.

Admittedly, that doesn’t make it a managed link yet, but it is a step towards it.

A caveat here is that “legacy” published URLs are expected to start with `/system/include`.

Comment: What will happen with a TCM uri/Webdav URL in child publications? Won't that break, or does DXA do the translation of publication id/name for you?

Comment: Good question. :-)  It won’t break. Most importantly, the item reference ID of the Page is obtained and that will be the same across the BluePrint. But it also obtains the title and filename (needed for rendering the XPM button) and those may be “wrong” if you localized the Page (because the DXA logic currently does not take care of changing the Publication).

Comment: Does content porter also automagically convert tcm uris in text fields to webdav URLs and back again when deploying from one CM to another?

Comment: No. That is why WebDAV URLs are recommended.

Comment: Thanks - I got it working with webdav URLs now. The docs could do with an update to make this clear: https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20DXA-v10/GUID-5E88B1FC-FA9A-46F0-B7A5-89FCF058DB23